# Versailles Garden and Palace - can we leave and re-enter on a Museum Pass

Tags: versailles

Can we renter the palace the same day, after we go out to eat lunch and come back to see the rest of the palace, we have the Museum Pass.

Comment: Not sure why people are voting to close this as an off-topic "Where should I go and what should I do?" question. It's a simple request about the conditions of a particular type of ticket.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, unlimited re-entry is possible so long as the pass is valid.  From [the FAQ on their website](http://www.parismuseumpass.com/rub-questions-reponses-16.htm), under the section "L'accès aux muses et aux monuments":

> - Peut-on visiter plusieurs fois le même musée ou le même monument avec le PARIS MUSEUM PASS?
>
>   Oui, avec le PARIS MUSEUM PASS vous pouvez visiter autant de musées et de monuments que vous le souhaitez, autant de fois que vous le voulez.

Or, from the [English version:](http://en.parismuseumpass.com/rub-faq-16.htm)

> - Is it possible to visit the same museum or monument several times with the PARIS MUSEUM PASS?
>
>   Yes, the PARIS MUSEUM PASS allows you to visit as many museums and monuments as you wish and as many times as you care to.